# odbc connection in python

Tags: python, pycharm

i am writing this code but nothing is happening

```
import pyodbc

def main():
    conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server}; server=DESKTOP;database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;autocommit=TRUE")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query ="create table Python_

ticket(ID int IDENTITY (1,1),NAME text,GENDER text, Comment text)"
    cursor = conn.execute(query)
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `print(cursor)` statement at the end of the `main()` function, and see what `cursor` is.

Comment: pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')